# Https CXF timeout

Tags: java, apache, timeout, cxf

I'm trying to use a WebService of a payment gateway which uses HTTPS as protocol and i'm using an apache cxf client.

The problem I'm getting timeout to all my requests, but when I use curl to the same WebService I get the response without any problems.

When i log into admin area of the payment gateway, all my tries are there without any errors, so i could say that the problem is somewhere in response.

The stacktrace are down below.

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
>     at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
>     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:510)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:440)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:343)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:295)
>     at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:75)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1074.authorize(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>     at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(Native Method)
>     at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:32)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:460)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:820)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
>     at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:224)
>     at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:148)
>     at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:468)
>     at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:401)
>     at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
>     at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1005)
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1509)
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1467)
>     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1375)

Comment: How long does the request take when using curl?  CXF has a default timeout of 60 seconds, I believe, so you may need to lengthen it.  If you need assistance configuring that timeout, please post the code/config used to create the CXF client.

Comment: Using curl it takes just one or two seconds and I get the response. I'm using 90 seconds for timeout but i still having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the receiveTimeout setting from Apache CXF src and replace the existing cxf-rt-transports-http-version.jar in your server.

See the instructions from [Wildfly 8.2/undertow read time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303854/wildfly-8-2-undertow-read-time-out)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are behind web proxy,that's why it working in curl but not through through Apache CXF.